# Cross Compiling a DVD Driver for Arm

Tags: compiling

I've just registered on the codeforge website & downloaded the Sunplus DVD Driver at:

http://www.codeforge.com/article/166926

I'm using Ubuntu 64 bit 12.04 & have installed the Linaro Toolchain for Arm. When I try to run '/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc' after cd-ing to the directory containing the extracted Sunplus DVD Driver, I get "arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files".

I've also tried '/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc sunplus.asm' (after cd-ing to customers: a directory within the extracted files, since sunplus is the dvd device name according to lsusb) but I get:
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld:sunplus.asm: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld:sunplus.asm:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I've also tried 'as sunplus.asm' (after cd-ing to the sub-directory containing customers) but get lots of errors e.g.
sunplus.asm: Assembler messages:
sunplus.asm:1: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'
sunplus.asm:3: Error: no such instruction:`sunplus_dvd *'
sunplus.asm:5: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `*'
sunplus.asm:6: Error: no such instruction:`sunplus.asm is standard iop config'
sunplus.asm:7: Error: no such instruction: `we can compile ioprom22_v.inc for customers'
sunplus.asm:8: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is`='
sunplus.asm:9: Error: no such instruction: `define SPHE8200 or SPHE8202'
sunplus.asm:10: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is`='
sunplus.asm:11: Error: no such instruction: `sphe8202 equ 1'
sunplus.asm:11: Error: no such instruction:`define it for SPHE8202'
sunplus.asm:12: Error: no such instruction: `sphe8200 equ 0'

I'm not a 'C' or 'Assembler' person. Can anybody tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

This driver does not seems to be for Linux for it seems to be for Windows. In the README, they say you must run `go.bat` but this is a MS-DOS script...

In C you must basically say

```
$ gcc main.c
$ ./a.out
```

when you have a source file `main.c` containing

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to find a Linux driver for a USB-linked external DVD drive. I would like to use this drive with my Android tablet. Ubuntu's syslog shows:

Comment: I'm trying to find a Linux driver for a USB-linked external DVD drive. I would like to use this drive with my Android tablet.
lsusb shows "Bus 002 Device 010: ID 1bcf:0c31 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Serial-ATA bridge". Ubuntu's syslog shows: "Bus 002 Device 010: ID 1bcf:0c31 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Serial-ATA bridge" but doesn't show any info about the driver. How can I find out?

Comment: Well probably it doesn't need any more driver. Doesn't it automatically mount on Ubuntu ? It should mount on `/dev`

Comment: I wasn't clear about what I want to do. The device works fine under Ubuntu (on my desktop). I don't use & don't want to use Ubuntu on my tablet. The device does not work under Android on my tablet. Therefore, I want to cross compile the driver. To do that, I need to find the source code. However, I don't know the name of it: I haven't been able to find out anything about the driver's source code location using internet search.

Comment: Other possibility is that a driver is not needed. So I just need to find out the kernel module, cross compile it for Android & install it on the tablet.

Comment: Yes, that might be a kernel module. Look at the output of `dmesg` on Ubuntu to see his name

Comment: I've done that and the module is ehci_hcd. I've used lsmod on my Android tablet & it doesn't show ehci_hd. So where can I find its source? PS However, when I plug in a memory stick & use dmesg: Ubuntu shows ehci_hcd confirmed by lsmod, whereas Android shows usb20_otg though neither lsmod nor cat /proc/modules show it!

Comment: And if you try to `modprobe ehci_hcd` ?

Comment: modprobe ehci_hcd shows nothing on Android. Thinking about it more after looking on the web, I think that ehci_hcd is not used by micro usb sockets/plugs. Thus, Android uses usb20_otg for memory sticks. Presumably, Android requires another usb..otg module for cdrom drives. I noted that someone said that Google lies about which kernel modules it uses. Anyway I'll carry on looking.